Why is my implementation of the Haar wavelet not normalized?
The Haar wavelet system is defined by
$$
\psi_{j,k} (x) = 2^{j/2} \psi(2^jx - k),
$$
where
$$ \psi (x) = \begin{cases} 
      1, & 0 \leq x < \frac{1}{2} \\
-1, & \frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1 \\
      0, & else.
   \end{cases}$$
By the definition, we have $|| \psi_{j,k}||_2 = 1$, for all $j,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is easily verified on paper.
Now I implemented this in Python (see below), however $|| \psi_{j,k}||_2 \neq 1$. Can someone tell me why? I think I'm missing something very basic and obvious here.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def haar_wavelet_function(t):
    return np.where((t >= 0) & (t < 0.5), 1, np.where((t >= 0.5) & (t <= 1), -1, 0))

j = 1
k = 1
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 128)
w = haar_wavelet_function(2**j*x - k)*2**(j/2)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, w)
plt.show()
print(np.linalg.norm(w, 2))


You're slightly incorrect regarding your definition $||\psi(x)||_2 = 1$. The correct one is:
$$||\psi(x)||^2_2 = \int |\psi(x)|^2dx = 1$$
Regardless, you're missing the step size $dx$:
dx = x[1] - x[0]
norm_w = np.sum(w**2) * dx
# or, if using np.linalg.norm 
# norm_w = np.linalg.norm(w, 2) * np.sqrt(dx)

Note that the sum is an approximation of the integral. The finer your step-size, the closer to $1$ you will get.
